# MultiValueDictKeyError at /add, Request method : GET

Tags: python, django, post, get, request

this is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'name':'irtiza'})

def add(request):

val1 = int(request.GET['num1'])
val2 = int(request.GET['num2'])
res = val1 + val2

return render(request, "result.html",{'result': res})
```

when i run this code i am getting this error,

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awk2p.png)

then i tried this code:

```
def add(request):

    val1 = int(request.GET.get(['num1']))
    val2 = int(request.GET.get(['num2']))
    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request, "result.html",{'result': res})
```

this error occur.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSpbD.png)

urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.home,name="home"),
    path("add", views.add, name="add")
]
```

home.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> hello  {{name}} </h1>

<form action="add">

    {% csrf_token %}

    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Result.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    Result : {{result}}

{% endblock %}
```

when i try POST function then it give error which mention below

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'name':'irtiza'})

def add(request):

    val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
    val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request, "result.html",{'result': res})
```

MultiValueDictKeyError at /add
'num1'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:7000/add?csrfmiddlewaretoken=t6mVWboKI37vxW3zDbVmpnB3j3g89EzjFhikDDMrB4qVEfrNyqG5pebeXgDLAFE0&num1=3&num1=3
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'num1'
Exception Location: C:\Users\irtiza\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 78
Python Executable:  C:\Users\irtiza\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4

what should i do now to resolve this error. This is just a simple function to ADD two numbers.Kindly help me.

Comment: I think you need to use `POST` method instead of GET

Comment: In your second attempt, try changing `request.GET.get(['num1'])` to `request.GET.get('num1', 0)`

Comment: The problem is with how you are calling the url and passing arguments

Comment: basically i have a home.html file where i create the form and took values and then i have button which have a function to add both numbers. the problem is when i hit submit button it throws me this error. "MultiValueDictKeyError"

Comment: Please post your errors as code, not images or image links.

Comment: i post the error in text :) when i use POST request as suggested by someone here.

Comment: ok thankyou guys for your assistance it is working fine now. special thanks to @ybl

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two times `num1` in your url as below...

```
url - http://127.0.0.1:7000/add?csrf.......&num1=2&num1=3
```

Change it to blow...

```
url - http://127.0.0.1:7000/add?csrf.......&num1=2&num2=3
```

And get it by below...

```
def add(request):

    val1 = int(request.GET.get('num1'))
    val2 = int(request.GET.get('num2'))
    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request, "result.html",{'result': res})
```

And Change this line from your form as below...

```
Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
```

Comment: i tried this function then it throws this error TypeError at /add
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: It means you are not getting any value from there. Are you pass both `num1` & `num2` in your URL?

Comment: yes i am passing both values in web form when i hit the submit button it throws me this error

Comment: Can you please add your form in question? I guess in your form you are given same name `num1` to your both input `num1` & `num2`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I edit my Question, you can review it now. I updated whole files of my project above

Comment: Did you changed in form as per I said in last edit of my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did the changes you mention above. actually the problem is in views.py then @ybl suggestion works perfectly. file.request.GET.get(['num1']) to request.GET.get('num1', 0)

Comment: But still you are use same `name` `num1` in your `form` for both `input` so, you have to change your second `input` field name as `num2` instead of `num1` in your form.

Answer (score 0):

Remove square brackets. It is not required.

```
val1 = int(request.GET.get('num1'))
val2 = int(request.GET.get('num2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I was missing ( method = "post or GET" ) in form in the home.html

The changes I have made are:

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> hello  {{name}} </h1>

<form action="add" method="POST">

    {% csrf_token %}

    Enter 1st number : <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'name':'irtiza'})

def add(request):

val1 = int(request.POST['num1'])
val2 = int(request.POST['num2'])
res = val1 + val2

return render(request, "result.html",{'result': res})
```

and then it works fine.